# Check Users Permissions on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to check if the user has accepted a list of permissions. I have this:

```
           window.FB.api("me/permissions", function (resp) {
                var IsValid = true;
                var perm = "public_profile";
                var PermsArray = resp.data;
                var PermsNeeded = perm.split(",");

                var Unit = PermsNeeded.length;

                for (var I = 0; I < Unit; I++) {
                    var Per = PermsNeeded[I];

                    if (PermsArray[Per] == null) {
                        IsValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                callBack(IsValid);
            });
```

When i try this, after i accepted the public_profile permission, i get IsValid = false.

Whats wrong? :s

**UPDATE:**
This works:

```
window.FB.api("me/permissions", function (resp) {
                var IsValid = false;
                var perm = "public_profile";
                var PermsArray = resp.data;
                var PermsNeeded = perm.split(",");

                var Unit = PermsNeeded.length;
                var UnitAccepted = PermsArray.length;

                for (var I = 0; I < Unit; I++) {
                    var Per = PermsNeeded[I];

                    for (var J = 0; J < UnitAccepted; J++) {
                        var AccPer = PermsArray[J];

                        if (AccPer.permission == Per) {
                            IsValid = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                callBack(IsValid);
            });
```

Comment: What is `resp.data`?

Comment: Its from facebook. Contains,  [Object { permission="public_profile", status="granted"}, Object { permission="read_mailbox", status="granted"}, Object { permission="email", status="granted"}]

Comment: So what is Per in the first loop? `public_profile` right? You said PermsArray was an array. Why are you checking if a key that is `public_profile` exists?

Comment: Yes, Per is public_profile first in the loop. PermsArray is an array with permissions from facebook. In PermsArray i will check if  my required permissions exists.

Comment: I found the solution i think :)